# Publishing and defining custom pre-requisites for application

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publishing, krypton-toolkit

I just developed a small application (vb.net) with Krypton toolkit elements in it.

On VS2012, I did "publish", zipped it and sent it to someone to test it. However, the receiver sent me an email stating that he got a message telling him he needs a component in order to run the application: "ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit Version 4.4.0.0".

My question is: how to overcome this obstacle? In order to run on a machine, does that machine need to have the Krypton toolkit installed in it? If so, how to install it as the application setup is run?

Thanks

Comment: Need some more information. Is this a winform or webform app? Are you sending the user the code or a compiled app?

Comment: I'm sending a compiled Winform application

Comment: Did you add references to the Krypton Toolkit in your app?

Comment: No, do I need to? I thought I could include the toolkit in the prerequisites of the "publish" options but I can't seem to find it. Also, I just tried to add the references but I don't find any Krypton related ones

Comment: OK... I'm not 100% familiar as I normally create WebForm Apps. But right click on your project... select Add Reference and then in dialog click Browse. Browse to the Krypton Toolkit DLL and add. You may also need to check the Application Files section in publish to make sure that all components required are included in the publish. Check your licencing of 3rd party code to make sure this is allowed.

Comment: @Mych, after "add reference", I select browse but there is nothing there. It just says "no items found". On the Application Files section in publish, there is the Krypton toolkit DLL and is set as "prerequisite (auto)"

Comment: If it is set as prerequisite then it would need to be installed on the client before the app will run. I'm downloading Krypton now to check out options.

Comment: Thanks. On the prerequisites dialog, I wanted to be able to select a "krypton toolkit" option such as the "sql server" or ".net framework", etc. That's not present and I don't know how to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Application Files section in Publish... where you have Krypton toolkit dll change Publish Status dropdown from Prerequisite to Include

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and report back to you